# How to save data in user specified location using pouchdb

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I am using javascript and pouchdb. It saves data in browser itself when I save the data but I want to make it save in perticular location. Please let me know how can I do it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
var db1=new PouchDB('mydb');  

var ws = fs.createWriteStream('file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/sevenadmin/db/output.txt');

db1.dump(ws).then(function (res) {
   res should be {ok: true}
});
```

mydb is the document name(table name). Whatever I have saved data in mydb, the same data should be saved in specified location.

I referred below link to save in specified location.
https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream

Comment: please tel somebody how can i do it.. I am trying from past 3 days

Comment: show us what you tried

Comment: I updated. Please check

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a browser environment, you can't control where data is stored - this is part of the browsers' security model. Otherwise you would be able to overwrite important files on your visitors' computers.

The example code of pouchdb-replication-stream is meant for running on the server, in Node.js.